# in react, when update state of a deep component, react will diff root tree or just the deep component tree?

Tags: reactjs

App component is the root component of project, Dog component is his grandson component.
when Dog component own state changed, how react diff? react will diff new and old App tree or just diff new and old Dog tree ?

Answer (score 0):

React will render  and it's children.

If you want to test this, put a `console.log()` in the `App` and `Dog` components, then change state in `<Dog />` (that doesn't get lifted up to `<App />`). The `.log()` in App won't write anything to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Answer below is based on react@17.0.2.

When state change occurs in child component, diff will always start from the root, more precisely, start from the “FiberRootNode” which contains the parent FiberNode of the root component's FiberNode.

Validation in development environment:
(1) Add a break point to the "renderRootSync()" function, which can be seen as the entrance of diff. This function is located at "node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js".
(2) Make a state change in a child(or grandson) component using a setter invocation.
(3) The precedure will pause at the break point as the screenshot below.
(4) You can continue to debug the diff process base on fiber mechanism step by step as you like.

[trigger break point when state changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6fz6.png)